# Trying to use oauth with facebook problems

Tags: php, facebook

Im trying to use this code to start building a simple facebook app but I cant seem to get to grips with the access token part so i can get the users birthday etc.

Can someone please take a look and let me know what im doing wrong :

```
<?php 
$app_id = "*********";
$canvas_page = "https://apps.facebook.com/hotness-battle/";

$auth_url = "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=" 
. $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($canvas_page) . '&scope=email,user_birthday';

$signed_request = $_REQUEST["signed_request"];
list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $signed_request, 2); 
$data = json_decode(base64_decode(strtr($payload, '-_', '+/')), true);

if (empty($data["user_id"])) {
    echo("<script> top.location.href='" . $auth_url . "'</script>");
} else {
    $token_url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=200482573356726&redirect_uri=http://www.impact25.com/hotness-battle/&client_secret=*******&code='.$data['oauth_token'].'';
    echo("<script> top.location.href='" . $token_url . "'</script>");

    $uid = $data["user_id"];
    $token = $data['oauth_token'];
    $full_name = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://graph.facebook.com/'.$uid))->name;
    $gender = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://graph.facebook.com/'.$uid))->gender;
    $birthday = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://graph.facebook.com/'.$uid.'?access_token='.$token))->birthday;
    echo $full_name;
    echo '<br><br>';
    echo $gender;
    echo '<br><br>';
    echo $token;
    echo '<br><br>';
    echo $cookie['access_token'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, obviously you just copied the above code from somewhere...here are a couple of tips:

1. Read the [Canvas Tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/tutorial/)
2. The second OAuth request is not needed (`$token_url`) since if the user authorized your app you'll have the `access_token` in the `signed_request`
3. Don't do multiple graph calls, one call will retrieve everything you need
4. Don't print the `access_token` to the user
5. Make *secure* calls to the graph ( `https` )

Here is a working code to get you started:

```
<?php 
$app_id = "APP_ID";
$canvas_page = "https://apps.facebook.com/appnamespace";

$auth_url = "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=" 
. $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($canvas_page) . '&scope=email,user_birthday';

$signed_request = $_REQUEST["signed_request"];
list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $signed_request, 2); 
$data = json_decode(base64_decode(strtr($payload, '-_', '+/')), true);

if (empty($data["user_id"])) {
    echo("<script> top.location.href='" . $auth_url . "'</script>");
} else {

    $uid = $data["user_id"];
    $token = $data['oauth_token'];
    $graph_url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/' . $uid . '?access_token=' . $token;

    $user_info = json_decode(file_get_contents($graph_url));
    $full_name = $user_info->name;
    $gender = $user_info->gender;
    $birthday = $user_info->birthday;

    echo $full_name;
    echo '<br><br>';
    echo $gender;
    echo '<br><br>';
    echo $birthday;
    echo '<br><br>';
}
```